# Problemas com menu dropdown com bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Fiz um menu dropdown em minha página. Quando eu seleciono o menu acontecem os seguintes problemas:
1) Não fica nada selecionado, ou seja, escolho a opção, mas não seleciona nada.
2) Mesmo não sendo selecionado nada, o menu fica aberto, fechando quando seleciono e nem se eu clico em algum lugar da página, não volta mais ao normal.

Esse código peguei na net para alterá-lo para meu uso.

Meu cshtml(view):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="Container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Technologies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Article</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">blog</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">News <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Technologies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Article</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta realizar a seguinte alteração:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

Adicionando o atributo `data-toggle="dropdown"`